# Difference in centroid, disc and shells

Tags: integration

There are formulas for calculating the centroid of a shape.

$$Centroid/Strips: (x,y)=(\frac{\int xy dx}{\int y dx} , \frac{0.5\int y^2 dx}{\int y dx} )$$

$$Discs: (x,y)=(\frac{\int xy^2 dx}{\int y^2 dx} , 0 )$$

$$Shell: (x,y)=( \frac{\int x\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx}{\int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx}, \frac{\int y\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx}{\int \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx}
)$$

I tried to search on Google about what they're implying but each page is about the derivation of formula of Centroid using Equilibrium of moments.

Can somebody please explain when are these formulas supposed to be used?(Maybe explain the distinction between Centroid/Strips, Disc and shells)

Comment: What is your source for these formulas?

Comment: My teacher told them and the first two are definitely used by the Cambridge International Examination board(saw those in a past paper)

Comment: Since you got them from your teacher, the best thing for you to do is to ask your teacher about them.  I always recommend students speak with their teachers more often, and this will help your teacher know that they have perhaps been unclear about these formulas.  Cheers!

Comment: I would've done that but contact to my teacher is not possible since I am on pre-exam vacations.

Comment: Ah.  My students can always get to me by email, but I guess not everyone has that option.  Cheers!

Comment: @mathnoob123 can you please let me know in which year was the discs formula used in the further maths exam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of formulaic teaching is disturbing. If you understand the definition of the centroid then you can attack any such problem. To that end we define the centroid as

$$\mathbf{R}=\frac{\int_D\mathbf{r}dD}{\int_DdD}$$

where $D$ is the domain in question; it can be a line, area, or volume and $\mathbf{r}=(x,y,z)$, as appropriate. This is seen to be a weighted average of the incremental elements with respect ot the origin.

So let's get specific, for a line, the domain is $S$ and

$$\mathbf{R}=\left(\frac{\int xds}{S},\frac{\int yds}{S} \right)$$

where $S$ is the line length and $ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}^2 \right)}\,dx.$

For an area, the domain is the area $A$ and

$$\mathbf{R}=\left(\frac{\int\int xdydx}{A},\frac{\int\int ydydx}{A} \right)$$

And finally, for a volume, $V$

$$\mathbf{R}=\left(\frac{\int\int\int xdzdydx}{V},\frac{\int\int\int ydzydx}{V},\frac{\int\int\int zdzdydx}{V} \right)$$

And the last thing you need to know is that when when you have compound shapes, for example, a square with circular cap, or a disk with hole in it, the centroid is the weighted averaged of the centroids of the components. For example,

$$R=\frac{R_1A_1+R_2A_2+R_3A_3+\cdots}{A}$$

where $A=\sum A_k$. If any of the areas are holes then they are simply *negative* areas.

With these definitions you should be able to calculate the centroid of any shape.

Comment: So basically Shell is centroid of a line, disc is the centroid of an object having a finite volume and Strips is the centroid of an object having a finite area ?

Comment: It's hard for me say what is meant by *disc*. To me it is a flat plate, or an area, but the integral in the denominator is a volume-or a centroid?

Comment: For disc, there was a question in which a line $y=kx$ was rotated 1 complete revolution around x axis and the centroid of the resulting shape was to be calculated through that formula. By this knowledge, I assume disc is a centroid for a volume object. What do you think?

Comment: Okay, so in this instance the disc is a *simple* 3D object.

Comment: What about shells and strips? Were my provided definitions in the first comment correct?

Comment: The strip is an area. Imagine the the when you rotate it about and axis it fills a solid volume. The shell starts life as a line; if you rotate you get an empty shell. So for example, a strip might lead to (solid) baseball and a shell to a (hollow) ping-pong ball.